# Rails documentation on RequestForgeryProtection for API requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, csrf, csrf-protection

I am reading notes on protect_from_forgery http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html and these few lines really confuse me.

> It's important to remember that XML or JSON requests are also affected  and if you're building an API you should change forgery protection method in ApplicationController (by default: :exception):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
end
```

> CSRF protection is turned on with the protect_from_forgery method. By default protect_from_forgery protects your session with :null_session method, which provides an empty session during request.

It was saying exception is the default for `protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }` but later saying null_session is the default for `protect_from_forgery`.

Does it mean that if we are using `protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }`, exception will become the default? And if we are using `protect_from_forgery`, null_session will become the default?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is accurate, if a bit confusing; each statement refers to a different "default" behavior. What the first statement means is that the default for new Rails apps is to generate your ApplicationController with this line:

```
protect_from_forgery :exception
```

What the second statement means, though, is that for the `protect_from_forgery` method, the default value of the parameter if omitted is `:null_session`. So if you were to remove `:exception` from your ApplicationController, i.e., you just had:

```
protect_from_forgery
```

Then the behavior used would be that of `:null_session` (see the [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d232499278e8f51d290e4c0554c46b38da1ff279/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L125) for proof).

So the first statement refers to the default generated code for new Rails apps; the second statement refers to the default value of the method itself. It's weird that they're different, though.